# Why the ModR/M:rm field is 100 in mov al, byte ptr [rbx + rsi*2 + 0x100]?

Tags: assembly, encoding, x86, machine-code, addressing-mode

The instruction

```
mov al, byte ptr [rbx + rsi*2 + 0x100]
```

is encoded to

```
8a 84 73 00 01 00 00
```

meaning that `ModR/M` is `0x84` or `10.000.100`

I understand the `mod` (`10`) and the `reg` (`000`) fields, but don't know why `rm` is `100`. Could anyone explain the rule used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rm field is 100 to indicate a SIB (scale index base) operand.  This operand is elaborated in the SIB byte, which if present, immediately follows the modr/m byte.  In this case, the SIB byte is `0x73` or 01.110.011, indicating a scale (01) of 2, rsi (110) as the index register and rbx (011) as the base register.

Refer to the Intel manuals for details.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't 100 an indication that the displacement length is 8? In this case the displacement is 32 bits long and therefore I would have used 101 instead.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia The displacement length is indicated byte the mod field. mod 10 indicates a 32 bit (or 16 bit) displacement.